# Rails 3 and Flex, the most generally used ways to connect them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex

I want to create an app with Flex as frontend and Ruby on Rails 3 as backend. I have some experience with Rails but I've never used Flex before. So, I'm searching for any information about how to use them together.

I found that there are RubyAMF, WebORB, RestfulX... But the most of information about them is outdated. What is used now? What editors or IDEs are used (I'm using Redcar for Ruby and I don't have any idea if it is compatible with Flex)? What version of Flex is worth using in production (it's 4, isn't it)?

Also I found "Flexible Rails" book but it describes Flex 3 and Rails 2. Maybe someone knows more modern books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redcar is an editor, I'm not sure what you mean by "compatible with Flex".

In any case, there aren't any more recent Flex + Rails-specific books.

Using Rails as a service layer and Flex as the UI layer would be the only thing that makes sense (assuming it makes sense to use Flex on the client side at all, which is debatable).

Other than version-specific differences, this still holds true for Rails 3 + Flex 4.5, as far as I know.

Comment: By "compatible with Flex" I mean that the editor has relevant plugins for Flex (e.g. form builder or something like this).

Comment: @immaculate.pine Then no, Flex Builder or other IDEs would be better suited. An editor is just an editor; you'll only get partial, and marginal, support beyond templates etc. Check for a Flex TextMate bundle, but even if there is one, an IDE is so much better (and this is coming from an Emacs addict). I use Intellij which has support for both.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to find IDE for myself. Also I started to read Flexible Rails book and it seems really useful in spite of it's age.

Comment: @immaculate.pine I thought it was pretty good, although I bailed on Flex soon after.